# Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven, зависимости, install

При сборке проекта консоль выдала:

```
    [INFO] Building smssender AMP project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Downloading: http://smslib.org/maven2/v3/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml
    [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to smslib (http://smslib.org/maven2/v3): smslib.org: С именем узла не связано ни одного адреса
    [WARNING] Failure to transfer org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from http://smslib.org/maven2/v3 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of smslib has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to smslib (http://smslib.org/maven2/v3): smslib.org: С именем узла не связано ни одного адреса
    [INFO] Downloading: http://smslib.org/maven2/v3/org/smslib/smslib/3.5.4/smslib-3.5.4.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.881 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-03T10:11:34+03:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/203M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project smssender: Could not resolve dependencies for project biz.justtrust:smssender:amp:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.smslib:smslib:jar:3.5.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.smslib:smslib:jar:3.5.4: Could not transfer artifact org.smslib:smslib:pom:3.5.4 from/to smslib (http://smslib.org/maven2/v3): smslib.org: Unknown host smslib.org
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Причина была в том, что не качались библиотеки. Пришлось скопировать директорию из maven другого компьютера.